# How to create head node

Tags: c, linked-list

I think I got it wrong in newList. Typedef struct  implementations must not be change. This is a lab assignment in my school.. Thanks in advance :)

```
#include<stdio.h>

    typedef struct node *nodeptr;
    struct node {
    int item;
    nodeptr next;
};
typedef nodeptr List;


List newList();
```

newList creates a header and returns a pointer to the header node

```
void display(List list);
void addFront(List list, int item);

List newList(){
    List list;
    list=(nodeptr)malloc(sizeof(List));
    list->next=NULL;
    return list;
} //I think my new list is incorrect..
void display(List list){
    nodeptr ptr=list;
    while(ptr!=NULL){
        printf("%d",ptr->item);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void addEnd(List list, int item){
    nodeptr temp, ptr;
    temp=(List)malloc(sizeof(nodeptr));
    temp->item=item;
    temp->next=NULL;
    if(list->next==NULL)
        list=temp;
    else{
        ptr=list;
        while(ptr->next!=NULL)
            ptr=ptr->next;
        ptr->next=temp;
    }

}
```

I can't seem to add 10 from the list..

```
int main(void){
    List list=newList();
    addEnd(list,10);
    display(list);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify our question, whats the purpose of your head node?

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways you can go about this depending on what you actually want (because just creating a node doesn't make a lot of sense by itself). But generally you have three common options — create it on the stack, create that node in the global memory, or allocate it dynamically. Below are some examples.

#### On stack

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int item;
    struct node *next;
};

int main()
{
    struct node head;
    head.item = 0;
    head.next = NULL;
    /* Do something with the list now. */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

#### In Global Memory

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int item;
    struct node *next;
};

static struct node head;

int main()
{
    /* Do something with the list now. */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

#### Dynamic Allocation

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    int item;
    struct node *next;
};

int main()
{
    struct node *head;

    head = calloc(1, sizeof(struct node));
    if (head == NULL) {
        perror("calloc");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    /* Do something with the list now. */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

You can read up on any of the above example in any introductory C book.

Hope it helps. Good Luck!